# Best way to show flowcharts on jsp page with google API

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm having a question about google api flowcharts. I wanted to add a couple of flowcharts on one jsp page. In my flowchart controller I run through the list I get from the database and I want to make foreach a flowchart.

What is the best way to add this to the model and show it on the jsp page?

Flowchart code is something like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

That code but with my values are filled in, in the for loop but I don't know how to give it to the model? (As String doesn't work I just tried :D)

Comment: does all your maps use the same div "chart_div" ?

Comment: you cannot do that.the maps will be over written. you have to use different div and register each one for setOnLoadCallback.

Comment: Thanks, any tutorial about this or example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code for displaying 2 charts in 1 page. You can tweak the logic and attain your requirement.
[Docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start)

```
      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart1() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
       function drawChart2() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div1"></div>
    <div id="chart_div2"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```